# How to replace all HTML characters to UTF-8

Tags: android, string, utf-8

I'm working on an Android project that reads some XML files and has to send them at some point.

If I have and String like this:

```
"<frequency_hygiene>about_once_every_2_&#8211;_3_weeks</frequency_hygiene>"
```

Is there any way to replace the HTML "&# 8211;" to its UTF-8 expression "–" dynamically? There can be other HTML codes so a...

```
mText.replace("&# 8211;", "–")
```

...it's not enough.

Thanks!

Mauricio

Comment: did you try mText.setText(Html.fromHtml("&# 8211;"));?

Comment: "HTML entities" is the right word.